# Customizing Markers on google maps from a kml layer

Tags: android, google-maps, kml, markers

I am loading a map in my app from kml layers and the kml files have several markers each. I would like to customize those, more specifically i want to show only the description of a marker without its title.
Here is what the kml looks like

```
<name>Point 1</name>

<description>N</description>

<Point>

  <coordinates>-3.19144566846689,55.94300165613873,0</coordinates>

</Point>
```

and I place the kml in my code :

```
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);

    // set kml layers
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

    InputStream inputStream = null;

    try {
        inputStream = new URL("http://www.inf.ed.ac.uk/teaching/courses/selp/coursework/monday.kml").openStream();

        // add a rectangle around the play area
        mMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions().geodesic(true)
                .add(new LatLng(55.946233,-3.192473)) //forest hill
                .add(new LatLng(55.946233,-3.184319)) // kfc
                .add(new LatLng(55.942617,-3.184319)) // buccleugh st bus stop
                .add(new LatLng(55.942617,-3.192473)) // meadows
        );

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        layer = new KmlLayer(mMap, inputStream, getApplicationContext());
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        layer.addLayerToMap();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I tried to find it in the documentation but I couldn't find how to show only certain information about a placemark.

Comment: Are you talking about the title/snippet in the InfoWindow for the Marker that comes up when you tap on a Marker?

Comment: Yes, currently when I tap on it it shows both the placemark's title and description and I would like to get only the description but i'm not sure hw to set the title to not be visible

Comment: Show how you are adding the Markers to the map.

Comment: they are just defined in the kml file and get loaded along with the map, i'll edit the question with a bigger part of the code in a sec